# Kotlin data class Jackson serialization/deserialization same object failed

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Currently I am working on a Kotlin project where we use Jackson for serialization/deserialization of our `data class`es. I start writing some unit tests and cover that when create an instance of `data class` after that serialize it and than deserialize it I received different objects.

Here what I mean:

My data class

```
data class TestEvent(
    @JsonProperty("stringProperty")
    val stringProperty: String,

    @JsonProperty("intProperty") 
    val intProperty: Int? = null,

    @JsonProperty("int32Property") 
    val int32Property: Int? = null,

    @JsonProperty("int64Property") 
    val int64Property: Long? = null,

    @JsonProperty("floatProperty") 
    val floatProperty: Float? = null,

    @JsonProperty("doubleProperty") 
    val doubleProperty: Double? = null,

    @JsonProperty("byteProperty") 
    val byteProperty: ByteArray? = null,

    @JsonProperty("booleanProperty") 
    val booleanProperty: Boolean? = null,

    @JsonProperty("dateProperty") 
    val dateProperty: java.time.LocalDate? = null,

    @JsonProperty("dateTimeProperty") 
    val dateTimeProperty: java.time.OffsetDateTime? = null,

    @JsonProperty("uuidProperty") 
    val uuidProperty: java.util.UUID? = null
)
```

The test

```
class SerializationTest {

    private lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mapper = ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(KotlinModule())
                .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    }

    @Test
    fun testJacкsonDeserialize() {
        val testEvent = createTestEvent()
        val serializedEvent = mapper.writeValueAsString(testEvent)
        val deserializedEvent = mapper.readValue(serializedEvent, TestEvent::class.java)
        Assert.assertEquals(testEvent, deserializedEvent)
    }

    fun createTestEvent() = TestEvent(
            stringProperty = "Test event",
            intProperty = 12,
            int32Property = 34,
            int64Property = 54L,
            floatProperty = 12.0f,
            doubleProperty = 566.0,
            byteProperty = byteArrayOf(3, 5, 7, 9),
            booleanProperty = false,
            dateProperty = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 20),
            dateTimeProperty = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 20), LocalTime.of(10, 0, 10), ZoneOffset.UTC),
            uuidProperty = UUID.fromString("2dd41a88-bf52-42ba-8ab9-d202139582ee")
    )
}
```

After I run the test receive this exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: 
TestEvent<TestEvent(stringProperty=Test event, intProperty=12, int32Property=34, int64Property=54, floatProperty=12.0, doubleProperty=566.0, byteProperty=[3, 5, 7, 9], booleanProperty=false, dateProperty=2020-01-20, dateTimeProperty=2020-01-20T10:00:10Z, uuidProperty=2dd41a88-bf52-42ba-8ab9-d202139582ee)> but was: 
TestEvent<TestEvent(stringProperty=Test event, intProperty=12, int32Property=34, int64Property=54, floatProperty=12.0, doubleProperty=566.0, byteProperty=[3, 5, 7, 9], booleanProperty=false, dateProperty=2020-01-20, dateTimeProperty=2020-01-20T10:00:10Z, uuidProperty=2dd41a88-bf52-42ba-8ab9-d202139582ee)>
Expected :TestEvent<TestEvent(stringProperty=Test event, intProperty=12, int32Property=34, int64Property=54, floatProperty=12.0, doubleProperty=566.0, byteProperty=[3, 5, 7, 9], booleanProperty=false, dateProperty=2020-01-20, dateTimeProperty=2020-01-20T10:00:10Z, uuidProperty=2dd41a88-bf52-42ba-8ab9-d202139582ee)> 
Actual   :TestEvent<TestEvent(stringProperty=Test event, intProperty=12, int32Property=34, int64Property=54, floatProperty=12.0, doubleProperty=566.0, byteProperty=[3, 5, 7, 9], booleanProperty=false, dateProperty=2020-01-20, dateTimeProperty=2020-01-20T10:00:10Z, uuidProperty=2dd41a88-bf52-42ba-8ab9-d202139582ee)>
```

How you can see both objects are the same, but the test fails and only thing which I see as a difference is in the Comparison View of the IDE which show some added empty space after the object generic tag, attach a screenshot:

[image]

Am I missing something? Could you give an advice here?

Answer (score 0):

After a day wondering and researching what actuality happened I found this post which save me:

https://medium.com/asos-techblog/what-you-didnt-know-about-arrays-in-kotlin-d3b20337e4

And the most important part is that:

> Kotlin compares the array’s references, not the content. In the Java class, Arrays.equals() is used to check the content, not the reference. Since we created two arrays here, they have different references.

So, if your data classes contains `Array` you have to override equals or change it with `List` otherwise the `equals` will not work properly.

Hope this will save at least one day for someone :)